# Canceling previous request in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, deferred

Using Angular I'd like to send only one data request at a time. I'd like to skip previous request when sending new one. To achieve it, I created global variable for request promise in my controller:

```
var searchRequest = null;
```

Then I defined a function to send requests:

```
function sendSearchRequest() {
   if (searchRequest != null)
      searchRequest.reject('new request');
   searchRequest = $q.defer();
   dataService.search(buildQuery())
      .then(function (result) { searchRequest.resolve(result); })
      .catch(function (e) { searchRequest.reject(e); });
   return searchRequest.promise;
}
```

It is a proxy function between my data service and higher level, which is supposed to cancel previous request if any and send the new one. Then I just call this function as follows:

```
function search() {
   sendSearchRequest()
      .then(function (result) { ... })
      .catch(function (e) { ... });
};
```

My query changes between two calls to `search()`, however I get the result retrieved for the first query. What am I doing wrong? Why can't I skip first request and get data from the second one?

Comment: Might i suggest a different solution entirely? such as a debounce? this is easily implemented in angular using model-options directive and will have a similar effect without having to worry with canceling previous requests. canceling the previous request doesn't save server resources, while debouncing will.

Comment: Yeah, different solution is appreciated too, if it allows to skip data from first request and get data from second one

Comment: with a debounce, the first wouldn't have even been sent. Why send a request if it's likely to get canceled anyway.

Comment: it depends on user's input. while the request is being send and processed, the user may change some params, and the second request will be sent.

Comment: What debounce does is it waits to tell you that something changed until a period of time has passed since the last change. This is ideal for performing a request based on a text field that the user is typing into.

Comment: it's not a text. it's about checkboxes. and may click them at any time. sometimes during the request.